# How to prevent PowerShell from opening a new window when executing a .lnk file?

Tags: windows, powershell

On Windows 10, I have created a shortcut to file python.exe, renamed it to python38.lnk and tried to use it with Windows PowerShell. However, it doesn't work as expected.

When I simply print `python38.lnk`, it opens the python console in a different window. When I print `python38.lnk --version`, it also opens a different window, prints output there, and immediately closes it so that I cannot actually read the answer.

When I print the full path to the .exe file, it works normally.

How do I make the .lnk file work in the same PowerShell window, as it is supposed to work?

(I have to mention that I am trying to make it work without any detours like adding the original .exe file to Path, etc.)

Comment: `.lnk` files are a vestige of Explorer, Windows' GUI shell - they're not like symlinks on UNIX-style filesystems. In PowerShell 7 you can do `& (Get-Item python38.lnk).ResolvedTarget`

Comment: Good point, @Mathias, but `.ResolvedTarget` only works on true reparse points, such as symlinks - for `.lnk` files it simply reports their own paths.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the heads up @mklement0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shortcut files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows) (`.lnk` and `.url` files) aren't directly executable *by the system*, they are a feature of the [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) (the GUI part of Windows), and *invariably* execute in a *new window*.

---

The *immediate* - but suboptimal - solution is to *extract* the executable path from the shortcut file (`.lnk`) and invoke the latter; e.g., assuming that your `python38.lnk` file is located in the current directory:

```bash
& (
    New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut((Convert-Path .\python38.lnk)
  ).TargetPath --version
```

Note that this assumes that your `.lnk` file is defined with *only* the Python executable path, and not also *with arguments*.

---

A better solution is, for instance, to create an [*alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) named `python38` that points to the Python executable path:

```bash
Set-Alias python38 (
    New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut((Convert-Path .\python38.lnk)
  ).TargetPath
```

You'll then be able to invoke the desired executalbe with `python38`.
If you place this alias definition in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file, it'll be available in future PowerShell sessions too.

Note:

- Unless you expect the executable targeted by the `.lnk` file to change, it's better to determine its path *once* and use its *literal* value.
- Aliases are only visible *to PowerShell*.